# Count last days in a range IF

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table of data that shows what hours employees have worked over the course of a week. Where a staff member has worked more then 5 days the 6th and 7th day (if applicable) is calculated at time and a half, from a base rate of $20 an hour.

I can count the number of hours where a staff member has worked 7 days week pretty easy i.e. IF counter =7 sum G3:H3, however I am stuck with counting the 6th day as this could fall on the Saturday or Sunday.

Does anyone know how I could count the last cell in the range that has data? The challenge is row six where the employee has worked Saturday and Sunday, with only Sunday which is the 6th day entitled to overtime.

Thanks

Scott

[image: Hours Worked]

Comment: What should the output be exactly? Should it be the total pay, by row?

Comment: ^ In other words, why do you need to determine if specifically Saturday or Sunday is overtime, if the base rate is always the same and each overtime day gets time and a half? Do you want the pay by day, or total weekly pay?

Comment: Im auditing and need two columns, base pay and overtime. OT is paid on 6th and 7th day working.  

Specifically where employees have worked 6 days a week I need to separate out normal pay and overtime. Normal pay is the first 5 days and overtime will 6th day. 

My formula will be IF count = 7 do this, If count = 5 do this, and if count = 6 do.....

                                                                                                                   So for the above its really just trying to add up the last number in a range, that might be on a Sat or a Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer via a reasonably simple formula

=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:H2<>""),B2:H2)

Scott

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula to add up the hours:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B3,0,0,,TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$7))),">0")>5,1.5,1)*(B3:H3))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Then to get the total pay just multiply that by 20:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B3,0,0,,TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$7))),">0")>5,1.5,1)*(B3:H3))*20
```

Still an array formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, would you mind explaining what this actually does. I'm not 100% sure what this is doing?